# How to darken the lower part of the background image?

Tags: html, css

I would like to darken only lower part of the image and ofcourse with linear gradient, so that it goes from light on the top to dark at the bottom of the div.

If there is the other option to do that with div, where the text is there?

Do you need to do that in css or style inside html?

My **html** code where that background image is: [image: picture]

```
<div id="content-wide">
<div class="post">
<div class="imgwide" style="background-image: url(image.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center;">

<div class="p-heading"><h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

<div class="p-content">
here is the text
</div>

</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

my **style.css** contains these entries:

```
#content-wide { 
 position: relative;
 width: 1180px;
 float: left;
 background: #F4F4F4;
 margin-bottom: 19px;
}

.imgwide {
width: 1160px;
height: 450px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#content-wide .post, #content .page {
 background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

#content-wide .p-heading {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left:0;
 width: 844px;
 height: 180px;
}

#content-wide .p-heading h1 {
 color: #F8F8F8;
 font-size: 26px;
 padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
}

#content-wide .p-heading h1 a {
 color: #F8F8F8;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: none;
}

#content-wide .p-heading h1 a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
color: #F8F8F8;
}

#content-wide .p-content {
 padding: 0px 20px 20px 30px;
 font-family: Frutiger, Lato;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 16px;
 text-align: none;
 color: #EAEAEA;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a CSS solution, check [Transparency Gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients), it works like this  :

```
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), url('your_url');
```

This will darken the bottom of your `background-image`.

[image]

---

If you do not want to darken the image but the div on top of it then use :

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 70%);
```

on your div (`.p-heading`).

Comment: It worked but I also want to know what to do to leave 80% of the picture, and do linear gradient only to 20% with css div if that is also possible.

Comment: @Techuser You can add/edit the `%` behind the  `rgba()` as you wish to do so.

Comment: I understand but no matter what you do it wont get darkened that text if not go darken the picture too, so if there is an option to do that with `<div class="p-heading">` would be nice. So that entire div will cover that lower part of the background image only. Is that possible? p-heading is 844px wide and 180px height.

Comment: Thank you! Great!